# Python removing duplicate names

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have plain text file with words in each line:

```
3210    <DOCID>GH950102-000003<DOCID>/O
  3243  Australia/LOCATION
  3360  England/LOCATION
  3414  India/LOCATION
  3474  Melbourne/LOCATION
  3497  England/LOCATION
  3521  >India<TOPONYM>/O
  3526  >Zimbabwe<TOPONYM>/O
  3531  >England<TOPONYM>/O
  3536  >Melbourne<TOPONYM>/O
  3541  >England<TOPONYM>/O
  3546  >England<TOPONYM>/O
  3551  >Glasgow<TOPONYM>/O
  3556  >England<TOPONYM>/O
  3561  >England<TOPONYM>/O
  3566  >Australia<TOPONYM>/O
3568    <DOCID>GH950102-000004<DOCID>/O
  3739  Hampden/LOCATION
  3821  Hampden/LOCATION
  3838  Ibrox/LOCATION
  3861  Neerday/LOCATION
  4161  Fir Park/LOCATION
  4229  Park<TOPONYM>/O
  4234  >Hampden<TOPONYM>/O
  4239  >Hampden<TOPONYM>/O
  4244  >Midfield<TOPONYM>/O
  4249  >Glasgow<TOPONYM>/O
  4251  <DOCID>GH950102-000005<DOCID>/O
  4535  Edinburgh/LOCATION
  4840  Road<TOPONYM>/O
  4845  >Edinburgh<TOPONYM>/O
  4850  >Glasgow<TOPONYM>/O``
```

I want to remove same location names in this list and it should look like this:

```
3210    <DOCID>GH950102-000003<DOCID>/O
  3243  Australia/LOCATION
  3360  England/LOCATION
  3414  India/LOCATION
  3474  Melbourne/LOCATION
  3497  England/LOCATION
  3526  >Zimbabwe<TOPONYM>/O
  3551  >Glasgow<TOPONYM>/O
3568    <DOCID>GH950102-000004<DOCID>/O
  3739  Hampden/LOCATION
  3838  Ibrox/LOCATION
  3861  Neerday/LOCATION
  4161  Fir Park/LOCATION
  4229  Park<TOPONYM>/O
  4244  >Midfield<TOPONYM>/O
  4249  >Glasgow<TOPONYM>/O
  4251  <DOCID>GH950102-000005<DOCID>/O
  4535  Edinburgh/LOCATION
  4840  Road<TOPONYM>/O
  4850  >Glasgow<TOPONYM>/O
```

I want to remove the duplicate locations name and docid should remain in the file. I know there is a way through linux using uniq but if I'll run that it will remove locations within different docid. 
Is there anyway to split it through every docid and within docid if location names are same then it should remove duplicate names.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the original order of locations that are within one docid  and do you care which location remains?

Comment: Original orders of the locations within docid is not required. I just want the locations within one docid should not have duplicate either it remove the location name with tag <toponym> or location name with tag /location.

Comment: Ok, i see that in your expected result you have two England's per first docid. Is that right?

Comment: I excuse for that but I suppose one England would work for me. because if it's two England in one docid it would be duplicate.

Comment: What do the numbers on the left represent? Where there is a duplicate these numbers are different. Does it matter which of the duplicates is kept?

Comment: numbers beside the location names are index of these words in a document.. so even if those indexes are different and location names are duplicate within docid I'd like to remove the duplicate locations within each docid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

```
import string
filename = 'testfile'
lines = tuple(open(filename, 'r'))

final_list = []
unique_list = [] # this resets itself every docid
for line in lines:
    currentline = str(line)
    if 'DOCID' in currentline:
        unique_list = []  # this resets itself every docid
        final_list.append(line)
    else:
        exclude = set(string.punctuation)
        currentline = ''.join(ch if ch not in exclude else " " for ch in currentline)
        city = currentline.split()[1]
        if city not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(city)
            final_list.append(line)

for line in final_list:
    print(line)
```

output:

```
3210    <DOCID>GH950102-000003<DOCID>/O

  3243  Australia/LOCATION

  3360  England/LOCATION

  3414  India/LOCATION

  3474  Melbourne/LOCATION

  3526  >Zimbabwe<TOPONYM>/O

  3551  >Glasgow<TOPONYM>/O

3568    <DOCID>GH950102-000004<DOCID>/O

  3739  Hampden/LOCATION

  3838  Ibrox/LOCATION

  3861  Neerday/LOCATION

  4161  Fir Park/LOCATION

  4229  Park<TOPONYM>/O

  4244  >Midfield<TOPONYM>/O

  4249  >Glasgow<TOPONYM>/O

  4251  <DOCID>GH950102-000005<DOCID>/O

  4535  Edinburgh/LOCATION

  4840  Road<TOPONYM>/O

  4850  >Glasgow<TOPONYM>/O``
```

Note: The `testfile`is a text file with your input text. You can optimize the code if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I am writing from mobile, so this will not be a complete solution, but the key points:

```
import re
Docid=re.compile("^ *\d+ +<DOCID>")
Location=re.compile("^ *\d +>?(. +)/")
Lines={} 
for line in file:
    if re.match(Docid,line):
        Lines={}
        print line
    else:
        loc=re.findall(Location, line)[0]
        if loc not in Lines.keys():
             print line
             Lines[loc] = True
```

Basically it checks each line of it is not a new docid. If it isn't, it then tries to read location and see if it already was read. If not, it prints the location and adds it to the list of locations tead.

If there is a new docid, it resets the last of read locations.